# CORS header origin move to application configuration file in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, configuration, asp.net-web-api

```
[EnableCors(origins: "www.example.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

public class DataCaptureController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Instance of Noise And Acceleration Data class.
    /// </summary>
    private SaveNoiseAndAccelerationData businessClass = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DataCaptureController"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public DataCaptureController()
    {
        this.businessClass = new SaveNoiseAndAccelerationData();
    }
}
```

So above `www.example.com` in the `Header` section I want to move it to my Application Config file.

So I have declared a static string and assigned the Application Settings parameter to it as below.

```
public static string IPConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IpConfiguration"];
```

If I do this I am getting an error as,

> `An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type" for the CORS parameter.`

```
public const string IPConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IpConfiguration"];
```

I get an error saying the expression being assigned to must be a constant.
So how can I assign the same from my Web.Config?